# Downloading Public Building(s) Lat/Log

Tags: data-request, geospatial, geocoding

Currently, I am working on a project that requires information for public buildings.

I was wondering what options are available to find the address and lat/log for each individual public building within a city? My project compiles of all individual departments within a city within a county. So I need the ability to see everything from a county and each city department within that county.

For example, all schools, parks, fire stations, police departments, city hall, etc. for the City of Columbus Ohio.

Comment: available options are going to differ and be practically unique to each locality in america. that data may be accessible for some localities online, but it most certainly is not for all. best bet is to contact each locality and request the data.

Comment: I'd suggest finding some service that converts street addresses to lat/long. Street addresses will be more generally available (associated with those buildings). But as *albert* commented, sources for addresses will vary widely. Maybe split your question into separate ones for obtaining the addresses, and then for the conversion (but check that those are not already here).

Comment: http://data-columbus.opendata.arcgis.com/

Comment: Thanks for help everyone. That is pretty much what I figured as well. Obtaining the addresses might be the next best bet.

Comment: openstreetmap.org and/or geonames.org might help-- but check the city/state website itself. My city (Albuquerque) has extensive GIS data online.

Comment: I originally posted and answer to a link with Chicago building outlines before realizing I misread the question. I deleted my answer but here’s the link for the curious: https://data.cityofchicago.org/widgets/hz9b-7nh8

Answer (score 1):

The City of Zürich, Switzerland just released the 3D building dataset.

[image] ([source tweet](https://twitter.com/OpenDataZurich/status/1062014106469838848))

The data can be explored and downloaded here: https://data.stadt-zuerich.ch/dataset?q=&tags=3d-stadtmodell

Here's [some examples](https://www.citygml.org/samplefiles/building/) of GML files to get started. And a bit about [City GML](https://www.citygml.org/), including other cities' datasets.

You can use [this Q/A](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/205838/112869) to convert GML positions to latitude and longitude.